# Bulk price change on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have a Magento store with 16.000 products and I would like to make some change to all product prices.
First of all I have only Regural Prices so I want to copy all the regural prices to special prices and then increase the regural prices +20%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this code in a file priceupdate.php on your root and run it via url e.g http://www.example.com/priceupdate.php

```
   <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::app('admin'); 
        $products_model =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->getCollection()    
                            ->addAttributeToselect('id')             
                            ->addAttributeToselect('price')  
                            ->addAttributeToselect('special_price')            
                             ->load();
    foreach ($products_model as $pid)
    {

        if(!$pid->getSpecialPrice()){

            $regularPrice = $pid->getPrice();
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid->getId()); 
            $percentage = (20 / 100) * $regularPrice;
            $newPrice = $regularPrice+$percentage;
            $_product->setPrice($newPrice);
            $_product->setSpecialPrice($regularPrice);
            $_product->save();
        }
    }   

    ?>
```

Comment: You are perfect!
It worked like a charm!

Comment: One more question:
This rule must be run only if Special Price is not set, beacause after importing new products it changes the already fixed prices

Comment: @CostasSaloubardos I have updated the code please check

Comment: hello and thanks for the response.
It icreases and the old products as the first script posted.
The point is to increase only if special price is 0 or not set (blank)

Comment: @CostasSaloubardos you can get special price $pid->getSpecialPrice() and do whatever you want with this

Comment: I think you don't understand what i mean.
The script works perfect for the products that is now in the store.
Then when I import new products with a bridge (that dont have a special price) and run the script again, it increases all the products (new and old), something that is wrong. It must increase only the products that dont have a special price.
I tried it and it increases all of them

Comment: @CostasSaloubardos I know what do you want, You want to increase those product's price which have no special price.I have added this line if(!$pid->getSpecialPrice()){  ... } it will allow to update only those product who has no special price

Comment: I have just check it and i does not work. It changes all the prices

Comment: I have posted the updated script. Please check I have forget to include  ->addAttributeToselect('special_price')    this line but it was added on my local system. check now

Comment: that is perfect! it worked fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since this doesnt display page output how long does the process take? 10,000 products, 100,000 products, etc...  Does the page have to but up the whole time or can the page be closed once started?

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan you can modify the script for output just add $count = 0; before foreach and add $count++; inside the loop and echo $count ; after the loop;